# Delegated yield (yield star, yield *) in generator functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ECMAScript 6 should be bringing generator functions and iterators. A generator function (which has the `function*` syntax) returns an iterator. The iterator has a `next` method which, when repeatedly called, executes the body of the generator function, repeatedly pausing and resuming execution at every `yield` operator.

The [ECMAScript 6 wiki on generators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators) also introduces the "delegated yield" `yield*` operator as follows:

> The `yield*` operator delegates to another generator. This provides a convenient mechanism for composing generators.

What does "delegate to another generator" mean? How can I use `yield*` to "conveniently compose generators"?

[You can play with generators in Node v0.11.3 with the `--harmony-generators` flag.]

Comment: The [wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators#delegating_yield) says, *"This is similar to a for-in loop over the generator,"*, so `yield* generator` should be similar to `for (i of generator) { yield i; }`.

Comment: if you know python, this is what [yield from](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) does.

Comment: Yield bomb? `(function*_(){yield*(_())})().next()`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*Delegating to another generator* means the current generator stops producing values by itself, instead yielding the values produced by another generator until it exhausts it. It then resumes producing its own values, if any.

For instance, if `secondGenerator()` produces numbers from `10` to `15`, and `firstGenerator()` produces numbers from `1` to `5` but delegates to `secondGenerator()` after producing `2`, then the values produced by `firstGenerator()` will be:

```
1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 3, 4, 5
```

```js
function* firstGenerator() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    // Delegate to second generator
    yield* secondGenerator();
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
    yield 5;
}

function* secondGenerator() {
    yield 10;
    yield 11;
    yield 12;
    yield 13;
    yield 14;
    yield 15;
}

console.log(Array.from(firstGenerator()));
```

Comment: Nice. It's obvious in hindsight, but I find specs hart to read. One improvement would be to add the example code that produces the result you mention.

Answer (score 5):

Delegated yield doesn't have to delegate to another generator **only**, but to any **iterator**, so the first answer is a bit inconclusive. Consider this simple example:

```js
function* someGenerator() {
    yield 0;
    yield [1,2,3];
    yield* [1,2,3];
}

for (v of someGenerator()) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

There isn't another function inside the generator itself - yet `yield* [1, 2, 3]` delegates to the [`Array.prototype[@@iterator]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) method.

Answer (score 3):

```
function *gimme1to2_10to15_3to5() {
    var ten = gimme10to15();
    yield 1; yield 2;
    for (var i = 10; i <= 20; i++)
        yield *ten;
    yield 3; yield 4; yield 5;
    }

function *gimme10to15() {
    for (var i = 10; i <= 15; i++)
        var x = yield i;
    }

let gen = gimme1to2_10to15_3to5();

var ar = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
    var r = gen.next();
    ar [i] = r.value + (r.done ? "!" : "..");
    }
console.log (ar.join (", "));
```

The result is

```
1.., 2.., 10.., 11.., 12.., 13.., 14.., 15.., 3.., 4.., 5.., undefined!
```

Notes

1. The function with **yield *** asks for 11 values from the inner generator but only receives the 10..15 that it should. The excess **yield *** calls have no effect.
2. The **done** value of the inner generator has no effect on the **done** that its caller returns.
3. The output shows **undefined!** at the end because the testing loop is written to go one beyond the required number of values in order to show the generator's **done = true**
4. This output is from the ES6 testing ground, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20%20%20%20function%20*gimme1to2_10to15_3to5%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20ten%20%3D%20gimme10to15%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%201%3B%20yield%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i%20%3D%2010%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%2020%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20*ten%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%203%3B%20yield%204%3B%20yield%205%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20function%20*gimme10to15%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i%20%3D%2010%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%2015%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%20yield%20i%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20gen%20%3D%20gimme1to2_10to15_3to5%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20var%20ar%20%3D%20[]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%2012%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20r%20%3D%20gen.next%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ar%20[i]%20%3D%20r.value%20%2B%20%28r.done%20%3F%20%22!%22%20%3A%20%22..%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%28ar.join%20%28%22%2C%20%22%29%29%3B%0A), and the semantics exhibited above should be considered provisional as at 5th Feb 2016.

Comment: Is `yield *ten` the same as `yield* ten`?