# What are ES7 Async functions?

Tags: javascript, function, async-await, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

I have been using Babel for a while now, and I am loving it. However, on the home page, where it lists the supported features, it says `Async functions`.

I have done a lot of Googling, and all I can seem to understand is that it's an ES7 feature.

Please what are ES7 Async functions?

Comment: Async functions are a horrible idea, letting you forgo promises and write asynchronous code line by line, without worrying about when things are done etc.

Comment: *Horrible?* It's basically the answer to C#'s `async`/`await` pattern. Misguided, maybe, horrible, no.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Javascript isn't C#, luckily, and it's a *horrible* idea

Comment: @adeneo, I assume you don't believe in convergence in technology, then :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - of course I do, but that doesn't mean I think all change is good, and this, in my opinion, isn't.

Comment: "ES7 Async" search ► [A Primer on ES7 Async Functions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-primer-on-es7-async-functions--cms-22367) It seems to explain everything there is to it as far as I can see.

Comment: I am not really interested in knowing if it's a good or bad idea. I just want to understand the concept. I am not a C# developer, so I don't know anything about C# async.

Comment: @adeneo: `async`/`await` does not forgo promises. It embraces them. It makes promise code with complex control flow a lot easier to read and write.

Comment: @Bergi - it's just syntactic sugar, it lets you return a promise from a function, and use `await` to write code like it wasn't async, line by line. It makes it easier to write, but in many cases harder to read, as most people are used to asynchronous functions having a callback, being thenable etc. and now suddenly, it isn't.

Comment: @adeneo: [Like generators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23613612/1048572), it empowers you to use all kinds of control structures with promises that you could hardly use before. And `async` functions are still thenable, every of them returns a promise! They are totally transparently exchangeable with normal promise-returning functions, like generator functions are exchangeable with iterator-returning functions (the only difference being `.toString()`).

Answer (score 5):

Async Await work with ES6 Promises. You can think of them as a way to write synchronous like code with Promises.

The `async` keyword marks as method that will make an asynchronous call. The `await` keyword marks the actual call.

With a promise you need to pass a method to the `.then()` method of the promise to to handle the result.

```
function doSomethingAsync() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // call Rest service and resolve here
    })
}

function printResult() {
    doSomethingAsync()
        .then(result => console.log(result));
}
```

This all works fine. With `Async/Await` we can write the last function a little different.

```
async function printResult() {
    let result = await doSomethingAsync();
    console.log(result);
}
```

The benefit of this is it simply reduces the need for callbacks.

For more see: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote. Also let me know if you are downvoting because you don't like the concept of async/await?

Comment: FYI, Promises are part of ES6 (ES2015) and `async/await` is **not** going to be part of ES7(ES2016).

Comment: Thanks for this example. I finally realized that `async` by itself is not to make a function asynchronous. That needs to be done using a `Promise`. `async` only marks some function as being able to use `await` and makes the function call to the async func appear synchronous-ish.

Answer (score 2):

[**ES2016**](http://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/) (commonly refered to as ES7 or ECMAScript 7) is the next evolution of the ECMA-262 standard (commonly referred to as JavaScript), and still at an early stage.

Async functions are a new JavaScript feature, proposed as a part of the ES2016 standard and not yet supported by any browsers. They're built on top of [**promises**](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises).

See below for an introduction to this new feature from various authoritative sources.

#### Note :

Even though Async functions are commonly refered to as `ES7 asynch functions` (eg. to disambiguate them from [**async.js**](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [**asynchronous JavaScript**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027) in general), [**Axel Rauschmayer**](https://twitter.com/rauschma) recommends [**not calling them that**](http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html), though, as a feature will only be included in the next standard once its proposal has reached stage 4.

Async functions are only at stage 3 right now. In fact, ES2016 will likely [**not contain async functions**](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/692489384654999552) (as [**Felix Kling**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) pointed out in the comments below).

---

From [**the stage 3 proposal**](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) :

> #### Introduction
>
> The introduction of promises and generators in ECMAScript presents an
>   opportunity to dramatically improve the language-level model for
>   writing asynchronous code in ECMAScript.
>
> A similar proposal was made with [**Deferred Functions**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:deferred_functions) during
>   ES6 discussions. The proposal here supports the same use cases, using
>   similar or the same syntax, but directly building upon control flow
>   structures parallel to those of generators, and using promises for the
>   return type, instead of defining custom mechanisms.
>
> Development of this proposal is happening at
>   [**https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait**](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait). Please file issues
>   there. Non-trivial contributions are limited to TC39 members but pull
>   requests for minor issues are welcome and encouraged!
>
> #### Status of this proposal
>
> This proposal was accepted into Stage 3 ("Candidate") of the
>   ECMAScript [**spec process**](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) in September 2015. The champion
>   intends for this proposal to be accepted into Stage 4 ("Finished") by
>   the end of November.
>
> #### Examples
>
> Take the following example, first written using Promises. This code
>   chains a set of animations on an element, stopping when there is an
>   exception in an animation, and returning the value produced by the
>   final succesfully executed animation.
>
> ```
> function chainAnimationsPromise(elem, animations) {
>     let ret = null;
>     let p = currentPromise;
>     for(const anim of animations) {
>         p = p.then(function(val) {
>             ret = val;
>             return anim(elem);
>         })
>     }
>     return p.catch(function(e) {
>         /* ignore and keep going */
>     }).then(function() {
>         return ret;
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> Already with promises, the code is much improved from a straight callback style, where this sort of looping and exception handling is
>   challenging.
>
> [**Task.js**](http://taskjs.org/) and similar libraries offer a way to use generators
>   to further simplify the code maintaining the same meaning:
>
> ```
> function chainAnimationsGenerator(elem, animations) {
>     return spawn(function*() {
>         let ret = null;
>         try {
>             for(const anim of animations) {
>                 ret = yield anim(elem);
>             }
>         } catch(e) { /* ignore and keep going */ }
>         return ret;
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> This is a marked improvement. All of the promise boilerplate above and beyond the semantic content of the code is removed, and the
>   body of the inner function represents user intent. However, there is
>   an outer layer of boilerplate to wrap the code in an additional
>   generator function and pass it to a library to convert to a promise.
>   This layer needs to be repeated in every function that uses this
>   mechanism to produce a promise. This is so common in typical async
>   Javascript code, that there is value in removing the need for the
>   remaining boilerplate.
>
> With async functions, all the remaining boilerplate is removed,
>   leaving only the semantically meaningful code in the program text:
>
> ```
> async function chainAnimationsAsync(elem, animations) {
>     let ret = null;
>     try {
>         for(const anim of animations) {
>             ret = await anim(elem);
>         }
>     } catch(e) { /* ignore and keep going */ }
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

---

From [**Jake Archibald**](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake?lang=nl)'s article [**ES7 async functions**](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) :

> #### Async with promises
>
> In the [**HTML5Rocks article on promises**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing), the final example show how
>   you'd load some JSON data for a story, then use that to fetch more
>   JSON data for the chapters, then render the chapters in order as soon
>   as they arrived.
>
> The code looks like this:
>
> ```
> function loadStory() {
>     return getJSON('story.json').then(function(story) {
>         addHtmlToPage(story.heading);
>
>         return story.chapterURLs.map(getJSON)
>             .reduce(function(chain, chapterPromise) {
>             return chain.then(function() {
>                 return chapterPromise;
>             }).then(function(chapter) {
>                 addHtmlToPage(chapter.html);
>             });
>         }, Promise.resolve());
>     }).then(function() {
>         addTextToPage("All done");
>     }).catch(function(err) {
>         addTextToPage("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
>     }).then(function() {
>         document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> Not bad, but…
>
> #### This time with ES7 async functions…
>
> ```
> async function loadStory() {
>     try {
>         let story = await getJSON('story.json');
>         addHtmlToPage(story.heading);
>         for (let chapter of story.chapterURLs.map(getJSON)) {
>             addHtmlToPage((await chapter).html);
>         }
>         addTextToPage("All done");
>     } catch (err) {
>         addTextToPage("Argh, broken: " + err.message);
>     }
>     document.querySelector('.spinner').style.display = 'none';
> }
> ```
>
> With async functions ([**full proposal**](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait)), you can `await` on a promise.
>   This halts the function in a non-blocking way, waits for the promise
>   to resolve & returns the value. If the promise rejects, it throws with
>   the rejection value, so you can deal with it using `catch`.
>
> **Edit:** I originally used `await` within an arrow function, [**apparently that's not allowed**](https://twitter.com/mraleph/status/449192750735704065) so I've replaced it with a `for`
>   loop. Domenic gave me a knowledge smack-down on [**why `await` can't be
>   used in arrow functions**](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/7).
>
> `loadStory` returns a promise, so you can use it in other async
>   functions.
>
> ```
> (async function() {
>     await loadStory();
>     console.log("Yey, story successfully loaded!");
> }());
> ```

---

From [**KoaJS**](http://koajs.com/) article [**The Evolution of Asynchronous JavaScript**](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/) :

> #### Generators / yield
>
> [**JavaScript Generators**](https://blog.risingstack.com/introduction-to-koa-generators/) is a relatively new concept, they were
>   introduced in ES6 (also known as ES2015).
>
> > *Wouldn't it be nice, that when you execute your function, you could pause it at any point, calculate something else, do other things, and
> >     then return to it, even with some value and continue?*
>
> This is exactly what generator functions do for you. When we call a
>   generator function it doesn't start running, we will have to iterate
>   through it manually.
>
> ```
> function* foo () {  
>     var index = 0;
>     while (index < 2) {
>         yield index++;
>     }
> }
> var bar =  foo();
>
> console.log(bar.next());    // { value: 0, done: false }  
> console.log(bar.next());    // { value: 1, done: false }  
> console.log(bar.next());    // { value: undefined, done: true }
> ```
>
> If you want to use generators easily for writing asynchronous
>   JavaScript, you will need [**co**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) as well.
>
> > *Co is a generator based control flow goodness for Node.js and the browser, using promises, letting you write non-blocking code in a
> >     nice-ish way.*
>
> With `co`, our previous examples may look something like this:
>
> ```
> co(function* (){  
>     yield Something.save();
> }).then(function() {
>     // success
> })
> .catch(function(err) {
>     //error handling
> });
> ```
>
> You may ask: what about operations running in parallel? The answer is
>   simpler than you may think (*under the hoods it is just a
>   `Promise.all`*):
>
> ```
> yield [Something.save(), Otherthing.save()];
> ```
>
> #### Async / await
>
> Async functions were introduced in ES7 - and currently only available
>   using a transpiler like babel. (disclaimer: now we are talking about
>   the async keyword, not the async package)
>
> In short, with the `async` keyword we can do what we are doing with
>   the combination of `co` and generators - except the hacking.
>
> [image]
>
> Under the hood `async` functions using Promises - this is why the
>   async function will return with a `Promise`.

Comment: Why is this answer getting downvotes?!

Comment: My two cents: I thought about it for a few minutes, and I ended up downvoting it because it is an aggregate of excerpts from different sources, with little to no original content. I recognize the efforts you put into formatting, but I still don't think we should encourage this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : **Thanks for your feedback!** What you're saying is in contradiction with my personal experience, though. Some of the highest rated answers I've seen on this website are just excerpts from authoritative sources with source references. Heck, the second most upvoted answer out of all the 281 answers I've put on StackOverflow so far is just two excepts from authoritative sources. So, in my experience, these are actually the answers SO users appreciate the most.

Comment: How old are these answers? What constitutes an appropriate answer tends to change with time here. Anyway, if your last sentence is true, then your answer should be upvoted back into shape very quickly.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : Good point. Time will tell! And again, thanks for your feeback!

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is **not** going to be part of ES7 (ES2016). Only stage 4 proposals are.

Comment: @FelixKling : According to the Stage 3 draft, the proposal is expected to be accepted into Stage 4 by the end of November 2016. Will that be too late? If yes, do you know of any sources that can confirm that?

Comment: @JohnSlegers: Yes, ES2016 is going to be released around June I guess. See also https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/692489384654999552 .

Comment: @JohnSlegers: And https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/692424625813377026: *"Any that are stage 4 by Thursday will make it in, yes."*. And https://tc39.github.io/process-document/

Comment: @FelixKling : **Thanks for that!** I added a note to my answer to reflect the point made in your comments, along with various minor improvements involving the naming of the upcoming Ecmascript standard.