# How to use await on fixture.whenStable in Angular 2 Tests

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-2017

[image]

Though `whenStable` returns a promise, I'm not allowed to use await.

Below are my tsconfig

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

I'm using `"typescript": "^2.1.5"`

Comment: Message is self-explanatory, make your function async.

Comment: it would be nice to have a way to make 'it' func async so we can use await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the error message: 'await' is only allowed within async function. When you want to use `await`, you have to mark the outer function with `async` keyword.

```
// example

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
   // ... some code
   await fixture.whenStable();
   // ... some code
}
```

When you mark any function with `async` keyword it returns a promise. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580109/what-are-es7-async-functions) for better explanation of async/await.