# What does this generator syntax do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga

What does the following syntax mean?  I don’t understand the use of a `*` after a yield.  I’m new to generators, redux, and sagas, so I would appreciate some help understanding what the syntax `*`, `takeEvery()`, and the `return function *(action) {` do:

```
var MIDDLEWARES = []

function builder( ) {
    const LOAD_DATA = "POI_LOADER/LOAD_POIS"
    MIDDLEWARES.push( function *sagaFunction() {
        yield *takeEvery( LOAD_DATA, loadData( statusField) )
    } )
}

const loadData = (statusField) => {
    return function *(action) {
        console.log("action.venueId = " + action.venueId)
    }
}
```

There are several questions here:

1. What does the `*` in `yield *takeEvery()` mean?  Seems to be answered by [Delegated yield (yield star, yield *) in generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491779/delegated-yield-yield-star-yield-in-generator-functions).
2. Why doesn't the builder() function need a `*` to make it a generator given that it contains a `yield *` statement?  Is that because the `yield *takeEvery()` is wrapped in the generator function `sagaFunction()`?
3. What does the `takeEvery()` function do, especially given that it has a `*` in front of it?  I think `takeEvery()`. Based on its [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/), I think it applies `loadData()` to everything in `LOAD_DATA`.  But if `LOAD_DATA` isn't an array, is `takeEvery()` needed in this code?
4. How come the declaration `return function *(action)` seems to have no name for the function?  Is it declaring a generator with input parameter `action` and assigning that generator for a `const` called `loadData`?
5. Does the Saga library call `next()` on the generators created in this code?

Comment: Is that legal? It looks strange. The `*` is part of the keyword, i.e. it is `function*` and `yield*`. I didn't know that whitespace is allowed, that's crazy.

Comment: [clicky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*)

Answer (score 1):

So generators allow to return a value from a generator function by using `yield` and then resume execution from there on the next call.

`yield*` is used to indicate that the value returned is coming from another generator - so the generator function that calls `yield*` is *delegating* the actual value creation to *another* generator function in this case.

See [MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) for more info.